# "Invalid use of non-static data member" when initializing static member from global variable

Tags: c++, static-members, member-initialization

```
class A {
    int x;
    static int i;
};


int x = 10;
int A::i = x;
```

When I compile the code above, it get the error

```
<source>:8:12: error: invalid use of non-static data member 'A::x'
    8 | int A::i = x;
      |            ^
<source>:2:9: note: declared here
    2 |     int x;
      |         ^
```

What's causing this error?

Comment: did you research this error yourself, e.g. in google? what have you learned?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is a peculiar language quirk - the scope resolution on the left, in `int A::i`, affects the lookup scope on the right, so that actually refers to the `x` member of `A`.

Either rename one of the variables, or specify the scope of the desired `x` explicitly:

```
int A::i = ::x;
```

Comment: Could you please give a reference to the standard?

Comment: I wouldn't call this a peculiar language quirk. Imagine if `A::i` were a function being defined out of line, rather than a static data member. You would expect that, inside the body of the function, `x` would refer to `A::x`. It's just that when the same thing happens in a static data member definition, it's a little bit surprising because we're not used to it.

Comment: @Evg http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.class#1

Comment: Probably best to use the scope operator to avoid an innocent-looking addition of a variable to `A` breaking the code.